# Amazon S3 different image dimensions with query string parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to store different dimensions of an image on S3. I am new to AWS Services, so it is taking some time for me to figure out how I can accomplish this.

Say I have an image called abc.png. I want to get different versions of this image using query string parameters, i.e apc.png?s=medium for medium 400x400, and abc.png?s=large for 1200*1200. I do not want to do a preprocessing, or on the fly resizing.

Is there a way to do this on the S3 level only?

Comment: No, not through query string parameters. Put the size in the image path instead: `/medium/apc.png` or `/apc.png/medium`

Comment: How do you propose the image will be resized, if you are neither preprocessing them to the sizes you want, nor resizing on the fly?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I will process them while saving to create different dimensions of course. What I meant by preprocessing is; I do not want an intermediary layer to process the querystring parameters and then return the corresponding image, I want the resulting urls to directly point to the resources.

Comment: @DarkFalcon Thanks for the proposal. /abc.png/medium approach would serve for my purpose. Is this a valid approach? I think I might run into problems on some browsers or distributions while serving images without the extension at the end

Comment: Browsers usually don't care about file extension. Just put the appropriate content-type header on the image by setting the content-type metadata attribute on each S3 object.

Comment: @DarkFalcon I've gone with your solutioni and its working good, thanks. If you write your comment as an answer I will accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The S3 API doesn't allow selecting a different file through the query string. Put the size in the image path instead: `/medium/apc.png` or `/apc.png/medium`. Don't forget to set the `content-type` option to the appropriate MIME type for each S3 object, which should allow the browser to render the images correctly.

Comment: will the browser cache these files or not if I use url of this type.(/apc.png/medium) ?

Comment: The same caching rules as are used for any S3 content will apply. See here for using custom headers to control the cache behavior of any S3 content: http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--how-to-set-cache-control-header-for-s3-object.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this service, they work with s3 as well I believe
http://cloudinary.com/